# Java Program to replace Text Files Dynamically

Tags: java

Am working on a project to replace Characters in a text files dynamically.

The Static text is

Dear Customer,
Thank you for registering with Our Company

Your registration was successful and an invoice has been generated on yourbehalf.
Please use the following invoice information when making payments:

Company Name: *Company_name*

ECS Number:  *ECS_code*

Invoice Number: *Invoice_no*

Amount Due: *Amount_due*

I want to replace the four parameters dynamically with a java method. companyname , ecsnumber , invoice number, and amount due

So far am only able to read the txt file , will need help on out I can replace this characters.

My sample Code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

      String filename ="C:\\Users\\Yemi-Plexada\\Desktop\\yemi.txt";  
        try {
            FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);

            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

             //Variable to hold the one line data
          String line;


          // Read file line by line and print on the console
          while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
            System.out.println(line);
          }

          //Close the buffer reader
          bufferReader.close();

        }
```

Comment: If this is a serious project (and not just an assignment), you may want to use a template engine.

Comment: What do you want to replace them with? As a hint: now you are printing out the line, something else should happen there.

Comment: Applying some String method such as `replace(key,value)`, once for each of the four keys, to all the lines should do the trick.

Comment: you should use a proper side effect free templating library like [`stringtemplate`](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)

Comment: I want to replace the Company name , ECS CODE , INVOICE NUMBER AND AMOUNT DUE....so the method goes like public replacetext (String example company, String Example Invoice file.txt) etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can call the `replace` method on string, as

```
 line = line.replace("Company_name", "WITH_ACTUAL_COMPANY_NAME");
```

Call all such `replace` method in the while loop you are using to iterate over all the lines.

Comment: You wouldn't have a String literal as second argument unless you want to rewrite the code for each new transformation?